# fill image in checkbox button in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical"
    tools:context=".TwitterHomeActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_line"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/settin_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/settin_img" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sonow_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/sonow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myviewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Checkbox"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_line"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:overScrollMode="never" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Checkbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/unlike"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/unlie_chkbox"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/like"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/like_chk_box_drable"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want like and dislike image fill copletely.I have added image.

here is some gap between them.
how remove it.
i am also want to show this in landscpe mode.it also fit in landscpe mode also.
please help me`

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `LinearLayout` with weighted child views instead of a `RelativeLayout`.
The solution would look something like this:

```
...
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Checkbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/unlike"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weight="1"
        android:button="@drawable/unlie_chkbox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/like"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:button="@drawable/like_chk_box_drable" />
</LinearLayout>
...
```

(By the way, `RelativeLayout` doesn't have an `android:orientation` attribute.)

Comment: sir i did it. but if i set image at background of check box then it work.but as i set image at button.so it not working.

Comment: @Parvesh, I don't understand what you mean. Do you replace the check boxes with buttons?